# why pug page not render in express js

Tags: express, pug

I'm new to pug i had create a sample file as shown below:

```
  .row
    .col-md-12
        .tile
            .row
                .col-lg-6
                    form
                        .form-group
                            label(for='exampleInputEmail1') Email address
                            input#exampleInputEmail1.form-control(type='email', aria-describedby='emailHelp', placeholder='Enter email')
```

This code works fine but when I paste the below code:

```
            .form-group
                label(for='hii') hii
```

My browser keeps loading and after a few minutes it shows "This page isn’t working", but if I remove the `hii` label it again works properly.

I get an error saying "Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both"

Comment: Do you have an input with the id of `#hii` too?

Comment: @sadrzadehsina no

Comment: @sadrzadehsina it throw error like Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the error message explains a lot.

In your editor make sure that you are using the setting that converts tabs to spaces, and make sure your tab space is "2".  That's what pug is expecting.

To fix your file, do a search and replace from tab to two spaces.